# How to use wildcard with variable

Tags: ansible

I want to list the files as per the host name.But problem is i not able to use the wildcard with variable properly.Can someone suggest me on this.

```
    ---
    - hosts: local
      become_user: yes
      vars:
          filename: /root/stuff

      tasks:
           - name: list files
             action: command ls -lrt {{ filename }}/'*{{ansible_hostname}}'
             register: listfiles

           - debug: var=listfiles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is *why * doesn't expand?*, then:

`command` module:

> The command module takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work

`shell` module:

> The shell module takes the command name followed by a list of space-delimited arguments. It is almost exactly like the command module but runs the command through a shell (/bin/sh) on the remote node.

So if you need any shell tricks, like wildcard expansion or access to environment variables, use `shell` module.

Comment: Thanks shell works fine in this case.

Comment: @samir if answers is correct, please mark it as accepted