# Non interactive samba user creation via ansible

Tags: ansible, samba

Although the following command works when typing in in shell

```
echo -ne "myser\nmypass\n" | smbpasswd -a -s myuser
```

The following task fails in ansible

```
  - name: add dms samba user
    command: echo -ne "myuser\nmypass\n" | smbpasswd -a -s myuser
    notify: restart samba
```

It does not produce any errors, but the user is not created.

Working with `ansible 2.3.0.0` on `Ubuntu 16.0.4.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use wildcard with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543220/how-to-use-wildcard-with-variable)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated, pipes won't work with the command module. I've used something like this in the past to create Samba users:

```
- name: Configure Samba users.
  shell: >
    (pdbedit --user={{ item.username }} 2>&1 > /dev/null)
    || (echo '{{ item.password }}'; echo '{{ item.password }}')
    | smbpasswd -s -a {{ item.username }}
  register: smbpasswd
  changed_when: "'Added user' in smbpasswd.stdout"
  with_items: "{{ samba_users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

The task will only run if the user does not exist yet. So changing passwords won't work with this example.

Answer (score 6):

I improved the code from [siwyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310119/siwyd) and [Tormod Macleod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12739227/tormod-macleod) slightly.
Thanks to both of you!

```yaml
- name: shell - create samba users
  ansible.builtin.shell: >
    set -e -o pipefail
    && (pdbedit --user={{ item.username }} 2>&1 > /dev/null)
    || (echo '{{ item.password }}'; echo '{{ item.password }}')
    | smbpasswd -s -a {{ item.username }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: samba_create_users
  changed_when: "'Added user' in samba_create_users.stdout"
  loop: "{{ samba_users }}"
  no_log: true

- name: shell - set samba passwords correctly
  ansible.builtin.shell: >
    set -e -o pipefail
    && (smbclient -U {{ item.username }}%{{ item.password }} -L 127.0.0.1 2>&1 > /dev/null)
    || (echo '{{ item.password }}'; echo '{{ item.password }}')
    | smbpasswd {{ item.username }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: samba_verify_users
  changed_when: "'New SMB password' in samba_verify_users.stdout"
  loop: "{{ samba_users }}"
  no_log: true
```

Changes:

- Added pipefail to satisfy Ansible Lint (https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html#risky-shell-pipe)
- Changed executable to /bin/bash, beacause /bin/sh doesn't know pipefail
- Added no_log to prevent password logging if the task fails
- Removed loop_control label, since logging is disabled
- Used loop instead of with_items
- Used FQCN

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. Note that ansible-lint also [prefers the use of FQCNs](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/rules/fqcn/) (`ansible.builtin.shell`).

Answer (score 3):

Please try this approach with your Ansible Playbook:

```
- name: set Samba passwords for each user
  shell: "printf '{{ item.passwd }}\n{{ item.passwd }}\n' | smbpasswd -a {{ item.name }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ users }}"
  tags: smbpasswd
```

Please note that you will need to map your variables file that includes `users:` with the format of:

```
users:
- name: userName
  passwd: myClearTextPassword
```

Please note that to support smbpasswd you will be passing this password as clear text. Additionally, noting this is only a single task that would need to be included in your playbook.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [siwyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310119/siwyd) above is excellent. I was struggling to figure out how to solve this problem in an idempotent way until I saw this. For my use-case, I'd like to keep the passwords in sync so I've added another play to do this. Might be useful for someone

```
- name: shell - create samba users
  shell: >
    (pdbedit --user={{ item.username }} 2>&1 > /dev/null)
    || (echo '{{ item.password }}'; echo '{{ item.password }}')
    | smbpasswd -s -a {{ item.username }}
  register: create_samba_users
  changed_when: "'Added user' in create_samba_users.stdout"
  become: true
  with_items: "{{ samba_users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"

- name: shell - set samba passwords correctly
  shell: >
    (smbclient -U {{ item.username }}%{{ item.password }} -L 127.0.0.1 2>&1 > /dev/null)
    || (echo '{{ item.password }}'; echo '{{ item.password }}')
    | smbpasswd {{ item.username }}
  register: verify_samba_users
  changed_when: "'New SMB password' in verify_samba_users.stdout"
  become: true
  with_items: "{{ samba_users }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.username }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

the command module does not support pipelining. use the shell module for stuff like this.

see:

- [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html)
- [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html)

Answer (score -1):

Another variant using dictionary lists:

```
ad_users: [
             { username: john.doe, password: P4ssw0rd*, givenname: John, surname: Doe, mail: john.doe@domain, ou: "OU=Department,OU=Division" },
             { username: jane.doe, password: P455w0rd*, givenname: Jane, surname: Doe, mail: jane.doe@domain, ou: "OU=Department,OU=Division" },
             ]


- name: Add user to AD
  command: samba-tool user create {{ item.username }} {{ item.password }} --given-name='{{ item.givenname }}' --surname='{{ item.surname }}' --mail-address={{ item.mail }} --userou='{{ item.ou }}'
  loop: "{{ ad_users }}"
```

Just remember to vault sensitive data.

Comment: `samba-tool` will work ONLY for computers with [ActiveDirectory](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/samba-tool.8.html) (Windows network). This does not cover typical cases when Samba is configured as FileServer.